# loopback 2 - defining an array of objects on a model

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

if I have a `usermodel` and I define:

```
"events": {
  "type": [
    "Object"
  ]
},
```

Do I need to define anything else in the `usermodel.js` to be able to post things like: `[{name: 'sample', ...}, ...]` to the user table's events column?

I ask because if I remove this particular definition from the `.json` the app compiles and the database migrates, but with it in, the app compiles but the database states there was an issue with the users `findByid`. My debugging has narrowed it down to this particular set of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can simply use this structure

```
{
 "events":{
    "type": [
       {
          "key": "type",
          "key2": "type"
       }
    ]
 }
}
```

You can see a .js example [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/examples/nesting-schema.js#L6) and .json example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/GcTO9nKAscs).
but I can also see an issue with the implementation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/GcTO9nKAscs) that says

> this model has problem.  When we fetch the data with any get call, it
>   renders this particular field as ["Object Object"] even though the
>   data is properly saved in the database.

which I would recommend you to try on your own as it will depend a lot on versions and drivers.

Though I would like to ask that what kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to define the object you want in the array as a model, then use that model as your type:

**Model: Class**

```
{
    "name": "Class",
    "base": "Model",
    "strict": true,
    "idInjection": false,
    "properties": {
        "label": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

**Model: Student**

```
{
    "name": "Student",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "strict": true,
    "idInjection": true,
    "properties": {
        "classes": {
            "type": ["Class"],
            "required": false
        },
    }
}
```